# jQuery: selecting items created in a loop

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop, hover

Newbie question: I have a loop which places a number of elements on a page, but when I reference the IDs I can only select the first one. Can someone tell me how I can apply the hover function to the items?

I am trying to achieve a page of dots, where each one fades in and out when hovered over. At the moment it just goes haywire when I select the first dot, and none of the others respond. Thanks in advance!

```
var dots = '';

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    dots += '<div id="dot" class="blue">&nbsp;</div><div id="dot" class="red">&nbsp;</div><div id="dot" class="grey">&nbsp;</div>';
}
//insert all
$('body').append(dots);                                 

// dot hover
$('#dot').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().fadeOut(200);
        }, function() {
    $(this).stop().fadeIn(400); 
});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` attributes **must** be unique within each page but you're repeating them, that's why `$('#dot')` only finds the first one. [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) has this to say:

> **id** = *name* [CS]
>   This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.

And [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute):

> The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character.

You should be using a class instead:

```
var dots = '';
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    dots += '<div class="dot blue">&nbsp;</div><div class="dot red">&nbsp;</div><div class="dot grey">&nbsp;</div>';
}
//insert all
$('body').append(dots);                                 

// dot hover
$('.dot').hover(
    function() { $(this).stop().fadeOut(200) },
    function() { $(this).stop().fadeIn(400)  }
);
```

Comment: All answers were not only similar but great, but I guess I have to accept the first one to keep it fair. Thanks all, and especially @mu is too short

Answer (score 0):

You can change your jQuery a little bit like this

```
// dot hover
$('div').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().fadeOut(200);
        }, function() {
    $(this).stop().fadeIn(400); 
});
```

OR

```
var dots = '';

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    dots += '<div id="dot" class="blue dot">&nbsp;</div><div id="dot" class="red dot">&nbsp;</div><div id="dot" class="grey dot">&nbsp;</div>';
}
//insert all
$('body').append(dots);                                 

// dot hover
$('.dot').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().fadeOut(200);
        }, function() {
    $(this).stop().fadeIn(400); 
});

});
```